# Creating half hour averages of a list

Tags: python, list, split

I have to calculate, the zero upcrossing period, averaged over half an hour, from a dataset.

The time measurement is the UTC-timestamp (# of seconds since 01.0.1970).
Every second there are about 2-3 measurements. The measurements for each day are stored in their own file.

The data acquisition unfortunately didn't start at the same time. Sometimes it started 6s after midnight, sometimes 10s and so on.  This leads to irregular numbers of measurements in during specific time periods. (there are not always the same number of measurements in e.g. half an hour)

So now I have to load the data from my file, then somehow find the measurements in the interval of 30min (1800s). Find all the zero upcrossings (the values go from <0 to >0) and then find all the corresponding time steps to calculate the period of the upcrossings and calculate the average of those. This then has to iterate 48 times.

So far I have made 2 attempts.

#### 1

```
def get_T_z(filename):         
#zero uprcossing period
heave=load_data_2(filename,2)
timestamp=load_data_2(filename,0)
zero_up_ind=[]  
# index of zero upcrossings
zero_up=[]      
#zero_upcrossing periods for each half hour
i=0
initial_time=0
day_len=int(timestamp[len(timestamp)-1]-timestamp[0])
count=0
while count<48:
    period=[]
    zero_up_ind=[]
    #stores the sum of the periods for each half hour    
    while timestamp[i]-timestamp[initial_time]<int(day_len/48):
        if heave[i]<0 and heave[i+1]>0:
            zero_up_ind.append(i)
    for c in range(0,len(zero_up_ind)-1):
        periods.append(timestamp[zero_up_ind[c+1]]-timestamp[zero_up_ind[c]])
    zero_up.append(mean(periods))
    count+=1
return zero_up
```

#### 2

```
def get_T_z_3(filename):
heave=load_data_2(filename,2)
#loads heave data from a file
timestamp=load_data_2(filename,0)
#loads the timestamp from a file
day_len=int(timestamp[-1]-timestamp[0])
#lenght of the day (number of rows)
t_init=0
#initial time
i=0
half_hour_time=[]
zero_up_p=[]
print(heave)
print(timestamp)
#the half-hour averages of the zero-ucrossing periods will be stored here
for count in range(1,49):
    zero_up_t=[]
    #the timestamps of the upcrossings will be stored here
    period_sum=0
    #stores the sum the periods
    if timestamp[i]<timestamp[t_init]+count*int(day_len/48):
        i+=1
    elif timestamp[i]==timestamp[t_init]+count*int(day_len/48):
        half_hour_time=timestamp[t_init:i]
        half_hour_heave=heave[t_init:i]
        t_init=i
        print(half_hour_time)
        print(half_hour_heave)
        for k in range(0,len(half_hour_time)):
            if half_hour_heave[k]<=0 and half_hour_heave[k+1]>0:
                zero_up_t.append(timestamp[k])
        print(zero_up_t)
        for c in range(0,len(zero_up_t)-1):
            period_sum+=zero_up_t[c+1]-zero_up_t[c]
        zero_up_p.append(period_sum/len(zero_up_t))
        print(period_sum)
return zero_up_p
```

When I execute the first code nothing happens. It just continues to run but nothing happens. I also tried a modified version of the code and some time later my laptop crashed. So maybe there is an infinite loop or something?
The second code just returns `zero_up_p` as an empty list. I have a feeling like it doesn't even start the `for` loop.

Edit1: I added the incrementation of i and changed the way the periods are averaged. My first code seems to be working now.

Comment: do you ever leave the `while timestamp[i]-timestamp[initial_time]<int(day_len/48):` loop?

Comment: side note. this `timestamp[len(timestamp)-1]` can be written `timestamp[-1]`

Comment: in the first attempt, `i` is never incremented

Comment: am I correct in understanding that `heave` and `timestamp` have the same size? and you need all `timestamp[i]` where `heave[i] < 0 and heave[i+1] > 0`?

Comment: do you need half hours as in *from 0:00 to 0:30*, or as in *from the first measurements to 30 minutes later* ?

Comment: ah yes i forgot to increment i. I will change that,no wonder i never leave the loop ;)

Comment: heave and timestamp have the same length yes, they are two different columns from the same file. 
And yes i first need the half hour from 0:00 to 0:30 then from 0:30 to 01:00 and so on.

Comment: ok I edited the i+=1 after the if statement and fixed another minor issue. Now i have an output, but every entry is the same. I will need to have a look at that ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to be working now:

```
def get_T_z(filename):         
#zero uprcossing period
heave=load_data_2(filename,2)
timestamp=load_data_2(filename,0)      
# index of zero upcrossings
zero_up=[]      
#zero_upcrossing periods for each half hour
i=0
initial_time=0
day_len=int(timestamp[len(timestamp)-1]-timestamp[0])
count=0
while count<48:
    periods=[]
    zero_up_ind=[]    
    #stores the sum of the periods for each half hour    
    while timestamp[i]-timestamp[initial_time]<int(day_len/48) and i<len(timestamp):
        if heave[i]<0 and heave[i+1]>0:
            zero_up_ind.append(i)
        i+=1
    for c in range(0,len(zero_up_ind)-1):
        periods.append(timestamp[zero_up_ind[c+1]]-timestamp[zero_up_ind[c]])
    zero_up.append(mean(periods))
    count+=1
    initial_time=i
return zero_up
```